# Gtk+2 Glade runtime errors fails to build widgets

Tags: gtk, runtime-error, glade

this is my code for a Gtk+2 application that uses glade file to build a menu.
But when I compile my software it generates following errors:

> Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_builder_get_object: assertion `GTK_IS_BUILDER (builder)' failed
>   Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_show: assertion`GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

```
drgeoToolbar::drgeoToolbar (geoView *view):
drgeoControl (view)
{
  GError* error = NULL;
  GtkBuilder *xml = gtk_builder_new ();
  GtkWidget *w;

  // Build the toolbars

  // take a reference of each bar item so we can :
  // . adjust their sensitivity
  // . attach a referecence of this class instance


  if (!gtk_builder_add_from_file (xml, DRGEO_GLADEDIR "/drgeo2.glade", &error))
  {
    g_warning ("Couldn't load builder file: %s", error->message);
    g_error_free (error);
  }
  setTopControlerWidget (xml);

  fetchWidgetParent (xml,&p_toolbar, "menuBar",
         (gpointer) this);
  fetchWidgetParent (xml,&p_zoomEntry, "zoomEntry",
         (gpointer) this);
  gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY (p_zoomEntry), "100%");
  gtk_builder_connect_signals (xml, &error);
  g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (xml));


  /* short cut bar */

  setShortcutControlerWidget (xml);
  fetchWidgetParent (xml,&p_shortcutBar, "shortcutBar",
         (gpointer) this);
  gtk_builder_connect_signals (xml, &error);
  g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (xml));



  gtk_builder_connect_signals (xml, &error);
  setPointControlerWidget (xml);
  fetchWidgetParent (xml,&p_pointBar, "pointBar", 
         (gpointer) this);
  w = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object(xml, "toolbar"));
  gtk_toolbar_set_tooltips (GTK_TOOLBAR (w), true);
  g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (xml));

  gtk_builder_connect_signals (xml, &error);
  setCurveControlerWidget (xml);
  fetchWidgetParent (xml,&p_curveBar, "curveBar",
         (gpointer) this);
  g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (xml));

  gtk_builder_connect_signals (xml, &error);
  setTransformationControlerWidget (xml);
  fetchWidgetParent (xml,&p_transformationBar, 
         "transformationBar",
         (gpointer) this);
  g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (xml));

  gtk_builder_connect_signals (xml, &error);
  setNumericControlerWidget (xml);
  fetchWidgetParent (xml,&p_numericBar, "numericBar",
         (gpointer) this);
  g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (xml));

  gtk_builder_connect_signals (xml, &error);
  setMacroControlerWidget (xml);
  fetchWidgetParent (xml,&p_macroBar, "macroBar",
         (gpointer) this);
  g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (xml));

  gtk_builder_connect_signals (xml, &error);
  setOtherControlerWidget (xml);
  fetchWidgetParent (xml,&p_otherBar, "otherBar",
         (gpointer) this);
  g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (xml));

}
```

Any ideas how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the very first error message.  You call `g_object_unref()` on the builder (many times even) yet keep using the builder afterwards.

Remove all but the the last unref call.  Same goes for those `gtk_builder_connect_signals()` calls.

Comment: The toolbar still isn't drawn.  
`#0  0x00007ffff6da9410 in g_log () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0  
    #1  0x0000000000437fca in drgeoToolbar::drgeoToolbar (this=0xf3c010, 
    view=<optimized out>) at drgeo_toolbar.cc:42`  
This is the backtrace result using gdb, after I did what you suggested. It still crashed. The line number 42 is the line 


`g_warning ("Couldn't load builder file: %s", error->message);`

Comment: Sounds like the xml file isn't where you think it is. As a general comment: There's several potential problems in the code... I suggest you start from the smallest  possible piece of code (like creating a builder from a file) and only add new stuff after you have all the error handling (including returns in the error path) and testing done for that piece.